# Give an example of limits that misbehave under conjugation of function

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

My quest: Find real valued functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ such that $f \rightarrow b$ as $x\rightarrow a$ and $g\rightarrow c$ as $x\rightarrow b$ but $g(f(x)) \nrightarrow c$ as $x\rightarrow a$

**I don't want your example as an answer** so please refrain from posting your example. I just want verification of my example:

$$f(x)=b$$
$$g(x)=\begin{cases}-c & x=b\\
c &\text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work, $g(f(x))$ is always equal to $-c$ in this case, since $f(x)$ is always equal to $b$.

Comment: In fact that example works just fine, since $\;g(f(x))=g(b)=-c\xrightarrow[x\to a]{}-c\neq c\;$ , unless $\;c=0\;$ , of course. BTW, why do you call this "conjugation of function"? Perhaps you meant "composition of functions"?

Comment: @Ian But that's what I want. The conjugation has a different limit from $g$ by itself. $g$ by itself has limit $c$ as $x$ goes to $b$.

Comment: Oh, never mind, now I see the goal. Yes, then it works out.